# I want to initialize the fragment every time the bottom navigation item is selected

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-nestedscrollview

The code below is a function that runs when bottomNavigation is clicked.

```
fun replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment)// 프래그먼트 교체 함수
    {
        Log.d("MainAcitvity", "fragment replace + $fragment")

        //Fragment Start Remove
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {
            remove(fragment)
            commit()
        }

        //Fragment Start Replace
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().apply {

            replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            commit()
            Log.d("MainAcitvity", "fragment replace start + $fragment")
        }

    }//end of replaceFragment
```

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when (it.itemId) {
                R.id.fragment1 -> {
                    adjustGravity(bottomNavigationView)

                }
                R.id.fragment2 -> {
                    replaceFragment(Fragment2)
                }
                R.id.fragment3 -> {
                    replaceFragment(Fragment3)
                }
                R.id.fragment4 -> {
                    replaceFragment(Fragment4)
                }
            }
            true 
        }//end of setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

But this is not working.

I'm trying to do this because I'm using CoordinatorLayout to scroll up the AppLayout function.

[image]

[image]

When I scroll down and go to the other Fragment,
It's not initializing as you can see in the picture above.

In NestedScrollView, the On Pause() for each Fragment will be displayed in the
I tried NestedScrollView.scrollTo(0,0), but it doesn't work.

I've also tried initializing OnCreateView(), but it doesn't work either.

I think the Fragments are working in MainActivity and the life cycle is a problem.

Below is an example of one of the Fragments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/CoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment3ToolbarFrame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="290dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:minHeight="50dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment3ImageView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/talk_toolbar_color" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fragment3_title_margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment3_title_margin_top"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/notosanscjkkr_medium"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="@string/fragment3_tag_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fragment3_title_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fragment3_subtitle_margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fragment3_subtitle1_margin_top"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/notosanscjkkr_regular"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="@string/fragment3_tag_subtitle1"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/fragment3_subtitle_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment3_tagText3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/fragment3_subtitle_margin_start"
                    android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/notosanscjkkr_regular"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="@string/fragment3_tag_subtitle2"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="12dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment3AppbarTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="225dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/notosanscjkkr_medium"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:text="@string/fragment3_tag_title"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="50sp"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

            </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/fragment3NestedScrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment3RecyclerView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addFloatingButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#447BE3"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_create_24"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:tint="@null" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I want to initialize the Fragment by any means. Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to initialize the Fragment again when you click for second time on BottomNavigationView use **setOnNavigationItemReSelectedListener** and replace your container with new fresh fragment that you need.

Comment: As you have informed, I tried to insert the replaceFragment function in the picture above on setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener, but it doesn't work the same.

Comment: Also, setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener is not what I intended. This happened when the same tab was selected.

Comment: @bombo how did you get to the mark?

Answer (score 1):

I added AppBarLayout.setExpended(true) to the initialization function.
Since then, my intended action has been successful. There was no need to refresh the fragment.